# Using Youtube_it with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, youtube-api, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to integrate youtube_it gem to utilise it to work with youtube videos for my Rails app.
As per the github page for [youtube_it](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it), It is suppose to be as simple as including the gem in your gem file `gem 'youtube_it'`

And that should be it. But it so happens that it does not recognise `YoutubeIt::Client.new` and gives an undefined constant error for the same.
As per the [sample app](https://github.com/chebyte/youtube_it_rails_app_example), I have done all the configuration needed for the same.

Any idea why does it not recognise `YouTubeIt::Client.new`
I'm new to Rails, so pardon me if this seems to be an easy question.

Comment: try to use it from console and check the error. same time prove all the valid credentials and try

Comment: I tried it. i did `require "youtube_it"` and it still fails. So that tells me that its not able to find it in the project scope itself.

Answer (score 1):

After almost an hour of research and no solution, i tried something which actually worked.
So what worked for me is adding the following two lines in my *Gemfile* after the `gem 'youtube_it'`
`gem 'inherited_resources'`
`gem 'acts_as_commentable'`

**This has not been mentioned on the [*youtube_it*](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) home page. It just says to include the youtube_it gem**

So i guess it turns out that we need to add these two dependencies and follow the configurations as per [youtube_it_rails_app_example](https://github.com/chebyte/youtube_it_rails_app_example) which uses youtube_it to build a demo app.

I did this and everything started working out as per expectations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the gem from github works for me

gem 'youtube_it', :github => 'kylejginavan/youtube_it'